# Proving a increasing function with algebra

Tags: proof-verification

I'm attempting to prove a quadratic function is increasing without any calculus, just using algebra facts. My question:

Consider the function $g(x) = (x + \dfrac{1}{2})^2 + \dfrac{7}{4}$

Prove that For every $x_1$ and $x_2$ in the interval [2,4], IF $x_2$ > $x_1$, THEN $g(x_2)$ > $g(x_1)$

This is what I've done so far:

$$(x_2 + \dfrac{1}{2})^2 > (x_1 + \dfrac{1}{2})^2$$
$$(x_2 + \dfrac{1}{2})^2 + \dfrac{7}{4} > (x_1 + \dfrac{1}{2})^2 + \dfrac{7}{4}$$
$$∴ g(x_2) > g(x_1)$$

Does that actually prove anything? Because by basic algebra that if $x_2$ is greater than $x_1$, the square of that will be bigger no matter what in the interval [2,4].

Also need to show what goes wrong with my proof if I instead use the interval [-2,4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is not quite right; what I'd do is notice that we can clearly move from $x_2>x_1$ to
$$x_2+\frac{1}2>x_1+\frac{1}2,$$
but, unless both sides are positive, squaring might not preserve the order - for instance, if we had $1>-2$ and squared both sides, we'd get $1>4$, which is wrong. So, before you write that $$(x_2+\frac{1}2)^2>(x_1+\frac{1}2)^2,$$ you need to check that both sides are positive. They are both positive if both $x$ are in $[2,4]$, meaning that the function is increasing in that interval, but if that range is extended to $[-2,4]$, it is possible to make one or both sides negative. In particular, if you choose any two $x_1,x_2<\frac{-1}2$, both sides are negative, and for $x_2>x_1$, it will be that
$$(x_2+\frac{1}2)^2<(x_1+\frac{1}2)^2$$
since when you square an inequality with negatives on both sides, you have to flip the direction of the inequality. So you could choose any counterexample from that range.

Comment: I may have been a bit unclear. For the first part, I'm showing just that the function is increasing based on the interval [2,4]. The second part is showing what goes wrong with my proof if I changed the interval to [-2,4], which it's suppose to go wrong. If that makes any sense.

Comment: Right; you got the right answer, but I'm saying that your method would be clearer if you, before assuming that you could square both sides, noted that $x+\frac{1}2$ is always positive in that interval; this strikes me as a key point in the proof, since it's what separates the first and second part, but you omitted it from your proof. It is, in fact, the part of the proof that goes wrong, so it's definitely important to includ.e

Answer (score 1):

First, plot the function:

[image]

You can guess from the plot and the form of the function that $g$ is non-decreasing on $[-{1 \over 2}, \infty)$.

So, suppose $-{1 \over 2} \le x_1 \le x_2$. Then $0 \le x_1 + {1 \over 2} \le x_2 + {1 \over 2}$, and since the function $x \mapsto x^2$ is increasing on $[0,\infty)$ (this is the key fact here), we have
$(x_1 + {1 \over 2})^2 \le (x_2 + {1 \over 2})^2$.
It follows from this that $g(x_1) \le g(x_2)$.

The $\ge {1 \over 2}$ is the important restriction in the proof. Without this constraint, we cannot use the fact that $x \mapsto x^2$ is increasing.

In the interval you asked about, $[-2,4]$, we can see that we can find $x_1,x_2 \in [-2,4]$ so that $x_1 < x_2$ and $(x_1 + {1 \over 2})^2 > (x_2 + {1 \over 2})^2$ (and so $g(x_1) > g(x_2)$). The reasoning above shows that we must have $x_1 < - {1 \over 2}$.

A quick look at the graph shows that $g(-2) > g(0)$ and a quick computation
verifies this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you've shown that the function on the interval $[2, 4]$ is increasing.

To see that $g(x)$ is not strictly increasing on all of $[-2, 4]$ take, e.g., $x_2 = 1 \gt x_1 = -2$.

We have $x_2 \gt x_1$, but $g(x_2) \lt g(x_1)$.  Can you see why $g(x)$ is increasing for all $x \in \left(-\frac 12, +\infty\right)$,  neither increasing nor decreasing at $x = -\frac 12$, and decreasing for all $x \in (-\infty, -1/2)$?

Answer (score 0):

All your functions (+, square) are monotonically increasing on the interval [2, 4], so their composition is monotonic too.

This speculation fails on the interval [-2, 4], because summation with constant is still monotonically increasing, but that can't be said about the square function.